# How to catch errors from worker threads in console application written in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

I currently have a small console application that runs a number of Tasks (using **Parallel.ForEach**) and each one of these tasks creates sub-threads using **ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem**.

I would like the application to handle any exception thrown by these tasks/threads.

Will surrounding the **Parallel.ForEach** statement with **try..catch** work if the threads throw any errors or will they just die out?

EDIT: These sub-threads simulate users of the system. Refer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312318/using-threadpool-within-loops-in-c)

Comment: Hi there should be some event handler to add for Thread.UnhandledException or similar...

Comment: Why would you call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` from within the tasks in the `Parallel.ForEach` loop?

Comment: If you surround Parallel.ForEach it should catch any exceptions thrown within any of the loop iterations. Would it be better to put the Try/Catch inside the for loop that way you catch the actual exception at the source rather than when it's thrown out of the Parallel method? Also probably depends on what exception you're trying to catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surrounding the statement will not do the job. You can do something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{             
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@".", "*.*");      

    Parallel.ForEach(files, x =>
    {
      try
      {
        MyAction(x);
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      }
    });        
}

static void MyAction(string x)
{      
  throw new ApplicationException("Testing: " + x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use QUWI. I have a brief comparison of background task types [on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html) (`Task`, `BackgroundWorker`, `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, and `Thread`).

For background tasks, `Task` is the clear winner. `QueueUserWorkItem` is very low-level by comparison.

In particular, your problem is error propogation, and `Task` has built-in support for this that is entirely lacking in `QueueUserWorkItem`. You *could* build it in yourself by wrapping your delegate in a `try`/`catch`, storing the exception as part of the delegate argument (or as a bound variable of a lambda expression), explicitly checking it later, and doing some [technically unsupported reflection](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/633822/allow-preserving-stack-traces-when-rethrowing-exceptions) to preserve the stack trace.

But why bother? `Task` supports error propogation out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

you can handle all exceptions with try/catch, for example:

```
try
{
    MyParallelMethod();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //...
}
```

and in your method, do something like that:

```
public void MyParallelMethod()
{
    var data = new List<String>(); 
    //...

    Parallel.ForEach(data, d =>
    {
        try
        {
            //...
        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            //...    
        }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Will surrounding the Parallel.ForEach statement with try..catch work if the threads throw any errors or will they just die out?

No, you need to put try/catch inside the sub threads.

Answer (score 0):

Error handling must be implemented in the task itself (the job each ). You need to make sure the task you are creating handles the exception.

`Parallel.ForEach` will not handle it for you since the exception will be raised not in the thread which is calling the `Parallel.ForEach`.

Alternative is to use `Task<T>`.